# Ненужные пути в архиве zip

Tags: zip

Столкнулся с проблемой, что если создать архив

```
 exec('zip -r -9 text.zip папка1/папка2/папка3');
```

в архиве путь будет папка1/папка2/папка3, но надо, чтобы было только папка3.
Пытался исключить папка1 и папка2 -x "папка1", но безрезультатно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй:

```
exec('chdir папка1/папка2 && zip -r -9 text.zip папка3');
```